# Ant Design Select - Select all filtered options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

It's possible to add an select all to filtered options or prevent the filter from clearing the search when i select an option?

Here is my select code:

```
<Select
        showArrow={true}
        suffixIcon={<CaretDownOutlined />}
        getPopupContainer={node => node.parentNode}
        mode={"tags"}
        value={this.state.domainsToClassify}
        bordered={false}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        placeholder={"Please select a domain"}
        loading={this.props.massiveLoading}
        disabled={this.props.massiveLoading}
        onChange={this.domainSelectChange.bind(this)}
        maxTagCount={0}
        maxTagPlaceholder={`${this.state.domainsToClassify.length} selected`}
        options={this.props.domainsMassive}
        optionFilterProp={'label'}
    />
```

And here is one Code Sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-gould-wlu1r?file=/index.js